# how to combine two columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a query

```
select
    city,
    month,
    month_number,
    sum(totalcount) as totalcount,
    sum(total_value) total_value
from
(
    select
        city,
        to_char( testdate, 'Mon') month,
        to_number( to_char( testdate, 'mm' ) ) month_number,
        count( totalcount ) totalcount,
        sum( total_value ) total_value
    from 
        testtable
    group by
        city,
        testdate
)
group by
    city,
    month,
    month_number
order by
    1,3
```

which is giving result as image 1, how to modify this query which can give result as image 2?

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: use Union All function

Comment: i need first row as city and under that months, suffer with order by clause, any help please

Comment: i'm trying in my local db need few min

Comment: i used this query 

 select substr(city,0,1)||'1',city,rownum as month,totalcount,testvalue 
 from( select city,count(totalcount) totalcount,sum(totalvalue) totalvalue from testtable group by city) -- order by 1 
 union all 
 select city,month,month_number,sum(totalcount) as totalcount,sum(testvalue) testvalue from( select city, to_char(testdate,'Mon') month,
 to_number(to_char(testdate,'mm')) month_number ,count(totalcount) totalcount,sum(testvalue) cod_value from testtable group by city,testdate) 
 group by city,month,month_number order by 1,3

added first coliumn with substr

Comment: its working now

Answer (score 1):

Use Oracle ROLLUP function in group by to achieve the desired result.

```
select
city,
month,
month_number,
sum(totalcount) as totalcount,
sum(total_value) total_value
from
(
    select
        city,
        to_char( testdate, 'Mon') month,
        to_number( to_char( testdate, 'mm' ) ) month_number,
        count( totalcount ) totalcount,
        sum( total_value ) total_value
    from 
        testtable
    group by
        city,
        testdate
)
group by
    city,
    ROLLUP (month,month_number)
order by
    1,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below SQL.

```
SELECT city, month,month_number
    sum(totalcount) as totalcount,
    sum(total_value) total_value
FROM   ( select
        city,
        to_char( testdate, 'Mon') month,
        to_number( to_char( testdate, 'mm' ) ) month_number,
        count( totalcount ) totalcount,
        sum( total_value ) total_value
    from 
        testtable
    group by
        city,
        testdate) x
GROUP BY ROLLUP (city, month,month_number)
ORDER BY 1,3
```

Comment: this is not giving required result set, as city and month column required in same column where grouping should happen city wise for all 12 month, i'm going with substr concept as i mentioned above.